# Wordpress unique background in posts that are in specific category

Tags: php, css, wordpress

i have a code:

```
<body <?php if( in_category( 11446 ) ) { echo "style=\"background-image: url('my-background-url-of-image');background-repeat:repeat;\" onclick=\"window.open('http://www.domain.com');\""; } ?> >
```

This code works only until page loads fully than something happens and it doesn't work i assume from inspect element that onclick function changes and i'm failing to find what part tricks that.

What this code does is it sets unique body background that are in specific category and background is clickable.

But because of some javascript error it doesn't work when page loads full so maybe somebody could explain me how to remove attr on Javascript and than add my with domain i want. Or maybe give example how to do alternative code just with href.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are building a Wordpress template and the background image to be used is based upon the category of a Wordpress post.

This uses no Javascript. Instead, what it does is create the CSS declaration block inside the head tag of the HTML5 document on the fly. It does no inline CSS for the body tag.

```
<?php
// ====================================================
// Solution #1
// Background Image Only
// ====================================================

function GetThisWordpressPostCategory() {
  // Do post category to filename mapping here
  return("cars");
}

function in_category() {
  // Just a dummy to simulate Wordpress in_category call
  return(true);
}

function BodyBackground($category) {
  $bodyCss = "";
  if (in_category($category)) {
    $bodyCss =<<<CSS
<style type="text/css">
body {
  background-image: url('{$category}.jpg');
}
</style>
CSS;
  }
  return($bodyCss);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Category background</title>
    <?php
    $category = GetThisWordpressPostCategory();
    echo BodyBackground($category);
    ?>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>


<?php
// ====================================================
// Solution: 2
// Clickable div spanning viewport
// ====================================================


function GetThisWordpressPostCategory() {
  // Do post category to filename mapping here
  return("cars");
}

function in_category() {
  // Just a dummy to simulate Wordpress in_category call
  return(true);
}

function PageCss($category) {
  $pageCss = "";
  if (in_category($category)) {
    $pageCss =<<<CSS
<style type="text/css">
html, body, #page {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url('{$category}.jpg');
}
#page-anchor {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
</style>
CSS;
  }
  return($pageCss);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Category background</title>
    <?php echo PageCss(GetThisWordpressPostCategory()); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="page">
      <a id="page-anchor" href="http://www.google.com"></a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, i'm not building new theme i'm using that code in header.php to simply display new background in posts that are in specific category but i'm failing to do so because onclick function does not work properly.

Comment: Why do you need to click to get a background image loaded? Just use my code. Its the same as specifying a background image based on the category but doing it through CSS instead of Javascript.

Comment: I want clickable background because i want to use advertisement of sponsors and once background clicked user would be redirected to sponsors website. At the moment with my code backgroudns displays but problem that it isn't clickable once website loads full. Your code is much better i can see but i don't know how to aplly clickable background with your code.

Comment: And this image is adaptable to responsive web design? So that it looks good in mobile, tablet, and desktop screen sizes?

Comment: That image i'm trying to put that would be clicable is 265x76 and i just use repeat css function. Main goal is simply make background that is clicable and with my code that i provided it works only until website loads full after that something happens with javascript that i fail to detect so maybe its possible to do with href instead.